# Spring Framework NullPointerException in controller JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I have this NullPointer. When i debuged the code i saw that **u is null** and **model is { }**. I guess that the modell is { } because of the exception but i do not know why i have null on user ?

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private DomainManager domainManager;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        User u = (User) session.getAttribute(User.SESSION_PROPERTY);

        Domain domain = domainManager.getDomain(u.getDomainId());
        Quota used = domainManager.getQuotaUsage(u.getDomainId());
        boolean active = domainManager.isDomainActive(u.getDomainId());

        model.addAttribute("domain", domain);
        model.addAttribute("active", active);
        model.addAttribute("used", used);

        return "home";
    }
```

**stack**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        bg.abv.saas.admin.controller.HomeController.showPage(HomeController.java:27)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
```

Comment: There is no variable with name of value `User.SESSION_PROPERTY` in session attributes. Model has to be `{}` since you didn't add something yet.

Comment: @Ken Bekov SESSION_PROPERTY is a static field in user class and it is not empty or null.

Comment: I mean, if `User.SESSION_PROPERTY` contains `"some string"`, there is no attribute with name `"some string"` in session. You have to figure out - why.

Comment: your user not authenticate so your sesion return null

Comment: @kakashi hatake how to authenticate the user when i can not open jsp file ?

Comment: Do you use spring sequrity ?

Comment: @kakashi hatake no, i do not use it.